# Read blob format

Tags: java, blob

I have a binary data blob as a String  (in hexadecimal), which does not come from a database, and I want to get the textual representation of it.

```
String b = "00000000000000000000000008004500003c65c34000400651acc0a800fec0a800fedb620ceaccd8bb4d00000000a0028018ba5100000204400c0402080a00f0de8e0000000001030306";

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
for(int i = 0; i < b.length(); i+=2) {
    baos.write(Integer.parseInt(b.substring(i, i + 2), 16));
}

byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
String blobString = new String(bytes);
System.out.println(blobString);
```

but when running it, I get:

```
�������������ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����E��ގ����ގ����<e�@�@Q����������b��ػM�������Q��@
��ގގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ����ގ��������
```

I know it should output something readable so I might do something wrong.
How do I get my binary data into a readable string?

---

I'm trying to read this (I separated the parts to make it clear):

```
/* Header */

d4c3 b2a1 0200 0400 0000 0000 0000 0000
ffff 0000 0100 0000

=======================================
/*First packet*/
/*Header*/
c1f9 7e48 //timestamp seconds
e913 0200 //timestamp offset microseconds
4a00 0000 //number of octet saved in file
4a00 0000 //actual length of packet = 74 bytes
/*Packet data*/
0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0800 4500 003c 65c3 4000 4006
51ac c0a8 00fe c0a8 00fe db62 0cea ccd8
bb4d 0000 0000 a002 8018 ba51 0000 0204
400c 0402 080a 00f0 de8e 0000 0000 0103
0306
```

When running into tcpdump, I get this output:

```
2008-07-17 09:50:25.136169 IP 192.168.0.254.56162 > 192.168.0.254.mysql: Flags [S], seq 3436755789, win 32792, options [mss 16396,sackOK,TS val 15785614 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
```

Comment: It is not readable, there is a lot of 0-bytes and non-ASCII byte values in there. It is some form of binary, definitely no text. You code looks more or less fine (it should specify an encoding, but in that case there is none :) If you would tell us something about the blobs origin, we might be able to help some more.

Comment: @eckes It comes from a pcap file capture. It's the  packet data after the first packet header. When running the pcap file with tcpdump I can see a IPs and other stuff into the terminal and I know it corresponds to this line. The documentation https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat tells that the data is a data blob of `incl_len` bytes but I'm unable to get the correct representation.

Comment: This is definitely not UTF-8 (judging by many zeros in front)

Comment: @dddsnn Well you're maybe right, but tcpdump is able to read those bytes into a readable form that's why I made this assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is part of a PCAP dump you need to parse it as a network packet. Or you write it out as raw bytes and use one of the available network analysers. Looking at the string I would expect the `45` to be the start of an [IPv4 header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header), then the `06` would be the protocol field (TCP in this case). `c0a800fe` (192.168.0.254) is the source and destination IP. And so on, you get the idea.

It seems to be a TCP SYN packet (first of a new connection), it therefore does not contain any payload.

```
--link--
000000000000 // src mac
000000000000 // dst mac
    0800 // ether type: IP
--ipv4--
4500003c // v4 5*32bit length
65c34000 // ID FLG OFF
400651ac // TTL PROT(6=tcp) CHECK
c0a800fe // ip.src
c0a800fe // ip.dst
---tcp---
db620cea // src.port 56162 -> dst.port 3306
ccd8bb4d // tcp.seq (=3436755789)
00000000 // tcp.ack
a0028018 // off  0x02=URG/ACK/PSH/RST/SYN(1)/FIN(0)
...
```

Comment: I'm dumb I think I need to sleep. But yes I guess this is the way to go. Thanks a lot

Comment: Just what does the link field corresponds to?

Comment: By that I mean how do you know the link field stops before 45 (so its length)? Is it arbitrary for any packet?

Comment: link level (below IP). typically stuff like sender/reciever MAC and ethernet frame type. pcap does not always capture those. 0800 is EthernetII's type for IP packet.

Comment: I was just looking for the "4" which is the start of IP, but reversing from there the other bytes fall into the Ethernet header (adjusted my answer)

Comment: As I will process the data not necessarily from a file, its' not possible to reverse but this is certainly documented somewhere. Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: The length of the link level header depends on the hardware protocol, if VLAN tagging is used or not and stuff. But basic ethernet has 6 byte MAC. AFAIK PCAP does not very well preserve this part of a packet (it might not record the headers at all).

Comment: The (file)Global PCAP header (not part of your dump) does contain a "data link type" field. I think this is used to know where the IP begins. See https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat and http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html I guess it is LINKTYPE_ETHERNET in your case.

Comment: Yes this is what I was reading, I'm getting the LINKTYPE_ETHERNET link type, so I can make my assumptions from there. :-) It's the 0100 0000 in the global header.

Comment: Have added more interpretation it fits the tcpdump output exactly. And does not contain any payload as it is a SYN handshake.

Comment: robust networks parses are quite hard (wireshark manages to get parser security bugs for years), so be warned. Piping it through existing tools might be easier. With "[tcpgrep](https://github.com/weary/tcpgrep)" you can filter out the tcp-stream payload text for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String blobString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```